# Unity 3d perforce corrupted scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine, perforce

Hello I use perforce to manage my Unity 3d projects. I use this plugin in Unity [p4connect](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/25523)

If I download the Project in a other Workspace as that one I have created it. Is the scene corrupted (the materials, scripts and other components) on game objects are missing.
I use a ignorefile which you can see below.

```
#Ignored files

.p4ignore.txt
*.meta
*.suo
*.user

#Ignored directories
Library
obj
Temp
bin
obj
```

Comment: Could you look at the two workspaces and see which specific files are missing from the second workspace?  That would make it possible to dig deeper and figure out why those files didn't make it from one workspace to the other.

Comment: The obj folder are not in the second workspace otherwise in the library folder the AssetVersioning and ShaderCache.db, CurrentMaximizedLayout.dwlt and the suo files in the base folder are missing. This are the only difference i see at the moment

Comment: Why is the "obj" folder in the ignore file if that's one of the folders that you need?

Comment: @SamStafford obj can be ignored in unity3d, it only contains generated files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **dont ignore meta files!**

Besides the fact that for a unity project your ignore is quite *clean* so to say, it never is a good idea to block the files that hold all the data on your object.

To fix this issue just remove the .meta ignore, and transfer it again.

As a small hint, you might want to expand the ignore file a bit to cover more useless files. The ignore looks very .GIT style alike. Which means you can most likely use [gitignore.io](http://www.gitignore.io) to generate a nice file, but just in case below follows a list of objects the other does not need/want

**files**
these files will be auto generated by Visual studio/monodevelop and project files

- *.csproj
- *.unityproj
- *.sln
- *.suo
- *.user
- *.userprefs
- *.pidb
- *.booproj

**Folders**

- [Ll]ibrary/
- [Tt]emp/
- [Oo]bj/
- [Bb]uild/

**Unity generated file on crash**

- sysinfo.txt

Answer (score 0):

Post your console exceptions here and try to remove the .meta ignore, and transfer it again.